# Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Im trying to use a script. And when I go to use it I get the following error:

> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /myred/include/functions.php on line 16
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /myred/include/functions.php on line 17

Now, Below is line 16 and 17 of the functions.php. Anyone have any idea what is wrong with it?

```
$reserved = explode("--",$reserved);
if (in_array("$dname", $reserved)) {
    $errormsg .= "$text_17<br>";
}
return $errormsg;
```

For reference, this is the script I am using: http://www.milliscripts.at/downloads/myred_14_mysql_5.zip

THANKS!

Comment: Error says it all, expected string, array given. Try: var_dump($reserved);

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AD7six wrong! From php.net: explode($delimiter, $string);

Comment: @ArtaexMedia that's late night activity for you :). @user1938508 - don't reuse variable names in code like this - it makes it hard to explain to you that `$reserved` is already an array - until you wipe it out and set it to null

Answer (score 3):

This line is the cause of your woes:

```
$reserved = explode("--",$reserved);
```

From the error message it appears the `$reserved` is already an array. I'm going to guess at it and say that each element of the initial `$reserved` array are strings that contain `"--"` that you want to split on.

If this assumption is right you'll need to convert `$reserved` to a string using `implode()`:

```
$reserved = explode("--", implode($reserved));
```

Which will solve the error and potentially give you the results you're looking for.

Comment: Doing this I now get Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Argument must be an array in /myred/include/functions.php on line 17

Comment: "on line 17" - you've put the code in a different place to where @leepowers has suggested.

Comment: No, I put it exactly where he suggested

Comment: @user1938508 not really possible. in the question `$reserved` starts as an array and gives you an error. the error you've quoted in the comment here says that `$reserved` is _not_ an array. At the very least you're making it difficult.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, on line 16, your trying to explode an array, look at the php manual for `explode`, it splits a string by any delimiter you specify.

Since `$reserved` on line 16 is failing, line 17 fails too because `$reserved` is not being set properly.

Post more code, we need to see where `$reserved` is first being declared.

Comment: For reference, this is the script I am using: http://www.milliscripts.at/downloads/myred_14_mysql_5.zip

THANKS!

Comment: I wont download that, but try this: remove this line `$reserved = explode("--",$reserved);`

Comment: From the code and warnings you're showing me, I'm assuming `$reseved` is already an array, so there's no need to explode it. So by removing `line 16`, `line 17` won't spit out a warning. The problem could be more complicated tho, I'd need to see more code.

Comment: Find out where the variable `$reserved` is first being declared, post that code.

Comment: After remove line 16 I get Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in /myred/include/functions.php on line 17

Comment: Like I said, it will be much easier if you locate the first declaration of `$reserved` and post some code.

Comment: function check_domain($dname) {
global $errormsg, $text_17, $text_18, $text_19, $minlength, $maxlength, $reserved;
// Check if special chars are in there
 if(ereg("[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]",$dname)) { 
  $errormsg = "$text_19<br>";
 }
// Check, if length is right
 if (strlen($dname) < $minlength || strlen($dname) > $maxlength) {
  $errormsg .= "$text_18<br>";
 }

Comment: This doesn't help, `$reserved` is a `global variable` which means that it's actually being declared elsewhere outside the function. Find that.

Comment: $adminmail = $row[adminemail];
$startpage = $row[home];
$pagetitle = $row[sitetitle];
$domainip = $row[domainip];
$maindomain = $row[maindomain];
$mailtoadmin = $row[mailtoadmin];
$language = $row[language];
$multiple = $row[multiple];
$minlength = $row[minlength];
$maxlength = $row[maxlength];
$reserved = $row[reserved];
$forbidden = $row[forbidden];
$autoappr = $row[autoappr];
$theme = $row[theme];
$rel = $row[rel];

Comment: Ok, now do this, as one other user mentioned, somewhere in your code do this `var_dump($reserved)`. Post the output here.

Comment: string(22) "admin--www--nic--whois" array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "admin" [1]=> string(3) "www" [2]=> string(3) "nic" [3]=> string(5) "whois" }

Comment: I tried again in a different place and now I get this string(22) "admin--www--nic--whois"

Comment: @user1938508 edit your answer such that reading your comments isn't necessary.

Comment: @AD7six dont understand what you mean??

Comment: answer->question - you are adding to the "question" in comments - don't do that. Edit the question so it's not necessary to see what else you've written

Comment: if (!empty($variableName) && is_string($variableName)){

// include your codes here. So, this will verify the the variable is not empty and is string.

}